# React Native Issue after Expo eject

Tags: react-native, expo

I checked many topic in stackoverflow but ı could not find ı hope there is no duplicated topic.

I ejected my expo project to react native but ı get error;

[image]

can you help me about this ?

my app.js

I get error on 35:41

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App(props) {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = React.useState(false);
  const [initialNavigationState, setInitialNavigationState] = React.useState();




  const containerRef = React.useRef();

  const { getInitialState } = useLinking(containerRef); // here 
  const config = {
    animation: 'spring',
    config: {
      stiffness: 1000,
      damping: 500,
      mass: 3,
      overshootClamping: true,
      restDisplacementThreshold: 0.01,
      restSpeedThreshold: 0.01,
    },
  };
```

Comment: it looks like you're using react-navigation 5, i'd suggest updating to the latest patch version and using `linking` instead of `useLinking`

also, can you provide more info about your app? is this a bare or managed app? can you try to provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, ı changed useLinking to Linking which is implemented from 'react-native' but it gives "_reactNative.Linking" is not a function. My app was working in expo perfectly than ı just type Expo eject for using react native libraries.

Comment: My application has simple routing like if user auth with firebase direct to register if not direct to root with tabbars